# The values for lat,lng returned by the provider are received as null in another page

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am obtaining latitude and longitude using the location. The code below is what I have set up. The reason I used a Provider here is that the latitude and longitude values change whenever the location changes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

class MapProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  double? lat;
  double? lng;
  Location location = Location();
  late bool _serviceEnabled;
  late PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;


  locateMe() async {
    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }
    await location.getLocation().then((res) {
      lat = res.latitude;
      lng = res.longitude;
      print('provider $lat long : $lng');
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

The latitude (lat) and longitude (lng) values are well returned from the provider I created. However, when I try to retrieve these values on the home page, it only returns null.

```
import 'package:capstone_flutter/provider/map_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_naver_map/flutter_naver_map.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Consumer<MapProvider> (
              builder: (context, naverMapProvider, child) {
                print(
                    'return lat: ${naverMapProvider.lat}, lng: ${naverMapProvider.lng}');
                if (naverMapProvider.lat == null ||
                    naverMapProvider.lng == null) {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
                return NaverMap(
                  options: NaverMapViewOptions(
                    initialCameraPosition: NCameraPosition(
                      target:
                          NLatLng(naverMapProvider.lat!, naverMapProvider.lng!),
                      zoom: 15,
                      bearing: 0,
                      tilt: 0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onMapReady: (controller) {
                    print("naver loading");
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 20,
              left: 10,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 2, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3))),
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/store_list');
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.list,
                        color: Color(0xFFBB0000),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "list",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
                bottom: 20,
                right: 10,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                      border: Border.all(
                          width: 2, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3))),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: (Icon(
                      Icons.my_location_outlined,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                    )),
                  ),
                )),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Container(
                width: 360,
                height: 44,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 2,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                    )),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.location_on_outlined,
                        color: Color(0xFFBB0000),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Text("address")
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The locateMe() method is called when logging in and pressing a button.
below code is LoginPage code.

```
import 'package:capstone_flutter/components/define_color.dart';
import 'package:capstone_flutter/mvvm/token_view_model.dart';
import 'package:capstone_flutter/provider/map_provider.dart';
import 'package:capstone_flutter/service/api_client.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  final TextEditingController idController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final MapProvider naverMapModelRepository = MapProvider();

  final ApiClient _apiClient = ApiClient();

  bool _showPassword = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TokenViewModel tokenViewModel =
        Provider.of<TokenViewModel>(context, listen: false);

    Future<void> login() async {
      dynamic res = await _apiClient.login(
        idController.text,
        passwordController.text,
      );
      print(res);

    
      if (idController.text.isEmpty || passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
        return null;
      }

      if (res['isSuccess'] == true) {
        tokenViewModel.updateAccessToken(res['data']['accessToken']);
        tokenViewModel.updateRefreshToken(res['data']['refreshToken']);
        await naverMapModelRepository.locateMe();  //I Use locateMe
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login_success');
      } else {
        print(res);
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 140,
            ),
            const Center(
              child: Text(
                'jatduree',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: idTextFormField(),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: passwordTextFormField(),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Checkbox(
                  value: isChecked,
                  onChanged: (bool) {
                    setState(() {
                      isChecked = !isChecked;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                const Text(
                  "store ID",
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/find_id_password');
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "find Id and Password",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFBB0000)),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 24,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: login,
                child: Container(
                  width: 500,
                  height: 60,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(DefineColor.loginBtnColor),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                  ),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(`your text`
                      "Login",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text("Do you have new Id?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      //fontWeight: FontWeight.wSymbol(figma.mixed),
                    )),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');
                  },
                  child: Text("Registration",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(DefineColor.loginBtnColor),
                        fontSize: 14,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        decorationColor: Color(DefineColor.loginBtnColor),
                      )),
                ),
              ],
            )
         ],
      ));
  }
}`
```

I really don't know what the problem is. Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using `Provider` wrong. The reason you get null is `MapProvider` is not the same instance in `LoginPage` and `HomePage`.

Instead of instantiate `MapProvider` in `LoginPage`, you should provide it up the widget tree, on node which are ancestor of both `LoginPage` and `HomePage`.

e.g. Above `App`:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MapProvider(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then you can access it in `LoginPage` like:

```
Provider.of<MapProvider>(context, listen: false).locateMe();
```

Comment: I made a foolish mistake, and I'm really, really grateful for you pointing it out. Thank you so much